# Blender release life cycle and versioning

Tags: versions

I was trying some older versions but version numbers and release versions are not clear to me.

For instance how can I know what is the most stable release of a given version, say 2.49:

The [folder listing](http://download.blender.org/release/) looks like this:

```
...
Blender2.49/    2009-Jun-04 09:24:18    -   Directory
Blender2.49a/   2011-Jul-11 16:08:09    -   Directory
Blender2.49b/   2009-Sep-16 09:53:26    -   Directory
...
```

So, which one is the stable release, is it the "newest one"?, so what does the letter **a** stand for, is it alpha?

How is it related with the [software release life cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle) common acceptance?

Comment: Usually letter differences in versions (i.e. 2.49*b*) are small changes in that version: a few bug fixes, small tweaks to tools or UI. Generally the most stable version will be the newest.

Comment: @CharlesL I'm not sure if the date in the listing is the build date, I'll assume it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, the letter doesn't stand for anything. It is appended to the version number when there is a bug fix release with minor changes after the initial release, and incremented with subsequent bug fix releases. So `2.49b` is the latest version of `2.49`.

The date refers to the last time the directory or file on the server was modified:

[image: Screenshot of server]