# Made Yin yang sphere from cylinder, how to add materials to the two regions separately

Tags: mesh, materials

Followed the Doc 2.4 wiki to make the tennis ball, [image]

I am stuck!

Edit:
Blender 2.71 makes it so simple, appended the object from the .blend made with 2.49, (tried making it from scratch in 2.71 but couldn't find anything to change the cylinder into a sphere as in 2.49). Anyhoo, voila! [image]

Comment: Any reason you are using 2.49?

Comment: The original tutorial is made with 2.49. Also, i have separated the regions with an edge loop. Now selecting each face individually from one region would be too tedious, isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: I've never used 2.4x much, so I'm not sure where the settings are.. There is a way to do this in modern blender in *3D view > Header > Select > Inner-region*. You should be able to just open the 2.49b file in 2.71 without any trouble, provided there isn't anything too complex (doesn't sound like there is). I ***highly*** recommend updating, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6744/599.

Comment: There is the *To sphere* operator (Alt Shift S), but I'm not sure if it's the same as whatever was used in 2.4..

Comment: You can also add a Cast modifier, Type=Sphere, factor=1.0. BTW, I may personally propose you [a better way](http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=73557) to do so. However, you have to notice that the Yin Yang Ball cannot actually be made to 3D form, in that case, the POV is quite limited.