# Several Missing Tools

Tags: versions

I seem to be missing several tools in Blender 2.62, or at least I'm not able to get to them the way the manual says they should be accessed. For example:

According to the Help file, the Bevel Tool is supposed to be accessible either with the Hotkey of CTRL-B or W > Bevel, or from Mesh > Edge > Bevel while in Editing mode, but it's not there. Nor am I able to access the Knife tool.

Any ideas where they've gone?

Comment: IIRC these features where added after 2.62. Any particular reason you are using that version? The current version is 2.73a

Comment: Partly because I only just started modeling again after a hiatus, so didn't update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The knife tool is in 2.62, however it's nothing like the modern knife tool. It was [rewritten into it's modern form in 2.63](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.63/BMesh#Knife) with the introduction of bmesh.

The [Bevel tool was also added in 2.63](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.63/BMesh#Bevel), after being missing since 2.5x.

However both these tools (and many others) have been improved *enormously* since then, so [I highly recommend updating to the latest version](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6744/599).

Comment: Yeah, I went ahead and updated. The part that had confused me is that the help file said it was there, but I guess didn't specify what version of 2.6 it was for. Thanks.