# How to add skytexture to viewport background?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, customization

I have a skytexture set up. How do I make this the viewport background?

I use Blender 2.72 and cycles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As of 2.73](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.73/UI#World_Background), you can do this by enabling *World Background* in *3D view > Properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Display*:

[image]

Comment: @NaioaiStudios Yes. Also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6744/599