# Make MouseLook actuator follow rig

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I have a simple character rig, and I want my *Mouse Look* actuator to work with my a bone in my character rig, not my object. How can I achieve this? I want my character head to look up when my mouse does. (Left and right does not matter)

Comment: I must be missing something.. What is wrong with [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12154/599)?

Comment: That is the object with no rig, my previous character. Now I have an updated one, with a rig. Character is one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the mouselook to the armature instead. After doing this, you will realize that the ENTIRE rig points to the center of the screen. Quite obviously, this would be undesirable.

To fix, go into edit mode, select the top half of the armature, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. Then <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of edit-mode and *Parent>Bone* the top armature to the top bone in the lower armature. see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19313/character-made-with-multiple-objects-one-armature-or-different-armatures/19316#19316) to do that if you can't figure it out.

Remove the mouselook from the bottom armature, or add it just too the top if you don't have it yet.

Comment: Did not work, P in edit mode does nothing. Please respond ASAP.

Comment: Pardon my mistake, [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[P]. Editing accordingly